# リモートPCでfastapiを起動したときに127.0.0.1でアクセスできてしまうのはなぜですか

Tags: python, fastapi

LAN内のリモートPCでfast apiをたちあげました。
main.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}
```

コマンド

```
uvicorn main:app --reload
```

なぜかローカルのブラウザで127.0.0.1:8000にアクセスすると、下記のように表示されてしまいます。
リモートのアドレスをいれているわけでもないのになぜでしょうか。

```
message "Hello World"
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

コメントを受けて画像追加しておきます。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ローカルのサーバーが動いているから以外に考えられません。

Comment: リモートにはどうやって接続してますか？VSCodeやなんらかのIDEのリモート機能を使って接続してませんか？

Comment: ローカルのpythonにはfastapiはインストールされていません。念のため素のターミナルからSSHではいって同じことを試しましたが、現象は発生しました。"{"message":"Hello World"}"

Comment: 普通にリモートのIPアドレスで、CORSの記述をして設定してサーバーをたてて、そのアドレスにアクセスする方法もできましたが、なぜ質問のやり方で通ってしまうのかが疑問です

Comment: SSH のポートフォワーディング機能を利用して、ローカルPCの8000番ポートへのアクセスをリモートサーバの8000番ポートへ中継していたりしませんか？

Comment: ローカルはwindowsだし、そんな高度な方法はそもそもどうしたらいいかもわかりません

Comment: SSHからctrl+cでサーバーをおとすとブラウザでアクセスできなくなります

Comment: 実際にはローカルPCからリモートのサーバにSSHでアクセスしているわけですから、ローカルの Windows PC には ssh コマンドがインストールされているはずです。具体的には `ssh -L 8000:127.0.0.1:8000 remote_server_ip_address` としますが、他のユーザが実行している場合も考えられます。(お一人で使われているのかもしれませんが)

Comment: 普通にSSHコマンドに　configファイルからhostname usernameしかわたしていません　鍵認証ではいっています
一人でつかっています

Comment: 仮想的なものはwslしかはいっていませんが、そういった間違いは絶対にありません。wslにもfastapiはいれてません

Comment: [このディスカッションをチャットで続行](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150600/discussion-between-peppaa-and-metropolis)しましょう。

Comment: いろいろためしてみてあやしかったのは、vscode経由でSSHしたときに、127.0.0.1:8080でブラウザを開くポップアップがあらわれ、そこをクリックすると現象がでていました。vscodeのリモート開発用のポート転送機能が使われていたようです。その後、ターミナルでやってもなぜかそれが残っていたようです。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 5):

Visual Studio Codeのリモート接続には接続先でリッスンしているポートを検知してポートフォワーディングを行う機能がついています。一度接続すると、Visual Studio Codeでリモート先を開いている間は有効です。別の方法でサーバーを起動しても、ポートフォワーディングによってリモートへアクセス可能です。

上記機能が有効だったと思われます。ポートフォワーディングについての知識がなくても、リモート先のサーバーへローカルのブラウザ等から簡単にアクセスできる機能になります。